# Whole header clickable instead of just the logo

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Working on a starting page for someone. I got a problem with the header.
Normally, the logo redirects you to the home page. But for some reason, the whole header is clickable instead of just the logo.
Here is the code;

```css
.page-header {
  margin-top: 0;
  background-color: #80a9ed;
}
```

```html
<div class="page-header">
  <a class="img-fluid" href="index.php">
    <img src="http://sitename.com/images/Flauwemoppen.png" width="140px;" style="margin-left: 3%;" alt="logo">
  </a>
</div>
```

Do I do something wrong?

Comment: can you give us a more complete code

Comment: maybe you need to put **class="img-fluid"** on the img tag and not the a tag

Comment: Possibly a bug. How are you viewing this code in action? Ive tried it on codepen and its ok

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logo anchor either has a block property or a with of 100%, Put a unique class suppose  'logo' on anchor tag  and then add this style 
.logo{display:inline-block!important;}